# Add line to Plotly Scattermapbox on button click

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to add a scattermapbox line on a button click & coming stuck. Does anyone know what the commands are to perform a refresh of the map div? My layout is below & I can draw the map on load using the following code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go    
data = [go.Scattermapbox(
    lat=[52.038459, 52.038459, 52.060934, 52.038459, 52.015984, 51.993509, 51.971034, 51.948559, 51.948559, 51.948559, 51.948559, 51.926084],
            lon=[-1.250252269, -1.2867081345, -1.323164, -1.2867081345, -1.250252269, -1.2137964035, -1.177340538, -1.1408846725, -1.104428807, -1.0679729414999999, -1.031517076, -0.9950612105],

    mode='markers',
            hoverinfo='none',
            marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
                size=5,
                color='black',
            ),
            # textfont=dict(color='red')
        )]

    layout = go.Layout(
        autosize=True,
        margin=dict(l=0,
                    r=0,
                    t=0,
                    b=0),
        hovermode='closest',
        clickmode='event+select',
        showlegend=False,
        mapbox=dict(
            accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
            bearing=0,
            center=dict(
                lat=51.672,
                lon=-0.953
            ),
            style='light',
            pitch=0,
            zoom=9
        ),
    )    
    app.layout = html.Div(id='pageContainer',
                              children=[
                                  dcc.Graph(
                                      id='mapContainer',
                                      figure={
                                          'data': data,
                                          'layout': layout
                                      }
                                  ),
        ])
```

However, when I've tried moving that same code into a button callback, it doesn't run. Any ideas? How do I force it to refresh & display in the mapcontainer graph?

Comment: How were you setting up the callback? Updating the `figure` prop of a `dcc.Graph` in the layout is doable, so maybe there was something else wrong.

Comment: Ah - I had the callback set up incorrectly as i didn't assign it to the figure property correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Could you possibly answer your question showing a working implementation here? @stephen.webb